# spring security oauth2 manually generate authcode

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

HI I am implementing oauth2 using spring security. This application will be deployed in a multi-node clustered environment. How spring will synchronize authorization code between multiple nodes? It can be achieved via jdbcAuthorizationCodeServices but I can't use relational DB. Requirement is to use NoSql DB. Is there a way to add custom plug-in custom authorization code generator which will be used by spring to create and consume auth code (Code example will be really helpful)? 
Thanks